# Set initial state of ng-show for orderBy in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-orderby

Trying to set the initial state of an arrow that I am showing for a list that is sortable. There are three columns and each one has a link bound to an `ng-click` that when clicked will sort the list.

It's working as I need it to but the state of the up and down arrows do not show until clicked. And when I click one the other disappears. What I would like is for all the arrows to always show even before the user clicks and for each one to change direction on click of any of the three.

The basic link is this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="orderByField='dateAdded'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="ghostButtonSort dateLabel flrt">Date Received
    <span ng-show="orderByField == 'dateAdded'">
        <span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span>
        <span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

And right now I just have a basic setup in the scope:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'conditionId';
```

Comment: So, first set to true in your condition....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the values with defaults in your controller:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'dateAdded';
$scope.reverseSort = false;
```

Here's a simple Fiddle that demonstrates working sorting behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/kxotrmj6/2/

In this demo you can change the sort column by clicking on column headings, and change the sort direction by clicking on the caret that appears next to the active sort column. This is achieved with:

**HTML**

```
<table id='peopleTable'>
  <thead>
      <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortOn = 'firstName'">First Name</a> 
          <i class="fa"
             ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse"
             ng-show="sortOn == 'firstName'"
             ng-class="sortReverse ? 'fa-caret-down' : 'fa-caret-up'">
             </i>
      </th>
      <!-- snip -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='person in people | orderBy:sortOn:sortReverse'>
          <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{person.favoriteColor}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sortOn = 'lastName';
    $scope.sortReverse = false;

    $scope.people = [
        {
            firstName: 'Joe',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            favoriteColor: 'Orange'
        }, {
            firstName: 'Jane',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            favoriteColor: 'Gray'
        }, {
            firstName: 'Zoey',
            lastName: 'Tester',
            favoriteColor: 'Blue'
        }];
}
```

I'm using [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io) for the carets, but you can use text, or images. `sortReverse` and `sortOn` are both initialized in the controller, so they have default values and will always be reflected in the UI.

Comment: That worked great thank you. Any idea on how to always show the arrows and not just when they are clicked?

Comment: Sure. You can remove `ng-show="sortOn == ???` on the arrow elements. With that gone, they will always display. However, this will introduce some confusing interaction for the user: does clicking on the arrow for a column also cause the sort to switch to that column? If so, you'll need to modify the logic a little bit. Instead of `ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse"` on the arrows, you'll probably want to move the arrow logic into a function on the controller so you can determine which column to sort. If you need help with that, let me know.

Comment: Yeah think I may. Let me code it up real quick and I'll post a new question. Thanks Nate.

Comment: Ok, ping me back here when you've posted it, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add you default value using ng-init like below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="orderByField='dateAdded'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="ghostButtonSort dateLabel flrt">Date Received
 <span ng-show="orderByField == 'dateAdded'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort" ng-init="reverseSort = true">^</span>
 <span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span></a>
```

Comment: My situation has not improved. So yes I guess my question would be how do I show the initial state of the sort or the arrow direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
<td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'firstName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        firstName :
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'firstName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'firstName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```